# 1st instance of a for loop exits if I am looking for a specific exit status

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to get some disk monitoring from a storage device . 
I can query the device and get out put .

e.g.  -- vol_list

```
dr_prdoracle_bkup  83%
dr_test  6%
infra_backup  3%
logs  28%
oem_shared  2%
prd_backup  51%
rhev_export  24%
ss_backup  2%
ss_data  23%
```

Here I am trying to alarm on percentage used . So here I am trying to create a warning @50% and Critical @70%

The thresholds are parsed on command line

```
WarnSpace=$2
CritSpace=$2


ST_OK=0
ST_WR=1
ST_CR=2
ST_UK=3

for line in $(cat "vol_list"); do
SpaceUsed=`echo ${line}|awk '{print $2}'|sed 's/%//'`
volume=`echo ${line}|awk '{print $1}'`

if [ -n "$WarnSpace" -a -n "$CritSpace" ]
then
    if [ "$SpaceUsed" -ge "$WarnSpace" -a "$SpaceUsed" -le "$CritSpace" ]
    then
                #echo "WARNING - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
                echo "WARNING; $volume: total $SpaceUsed"%""
        exit $ST_WR
           elif [ "$SpaceUsed" -ge "$CritSpace" ]
    then
                #echo "CRITICAL - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
                echo "CRITICAL; $volume: total $SpaceUsed"%""

        exit $ST_CR


fi
done
```

When I use the exit status it breaks out of the loop 
e.g.

```
./purefs_check.sh  -w 50 -c 70

WARNING; dev_client: total 67%
```

If I remove the exit code I get what I expect

```
WARNING; dev_client: total 67%
CRITICAL; dev_data: total 89%
CRITICAL; dev_vendor: total 99%
WARNING; dr_client: total 54%
CRITICAL; dr_prdoracle_bkup: total 78%
WARNING; prd_backup: total 51%
```

WHat I need i to finish the loop and give me an exit status of 1 for Warning and 2 for Critical .

Preferably only 1 exit code >1 entries .

So here I would like to see

```
./purefs_check.sh  -w 50 -c 70 |grep WAR ;echo $?
WARNING; dev_client: total 67%
WARNING; dr_client: total 54%
WARNING; prd_backup: total 51%
1
CRITICAL; dev_data: total 89%
CRITICAL; dev_vendor: total 99%
CRITICAL; dr_prdoracle_bkup: total 78%
2
```

Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: I might be out-of-date here, but if that’s a script for nagios, I thought nagios expected only one line of warning or critical output. You’d like the multiple filesystem reports into one line.

Comment: Hi Jeff . There maybe an occurrence where there is more than 1 volume breaching thresholds . That's why I would like clarity on the output .

Answer (score 2):

[`exit` will exit the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exit), immediately. If you want to set an exit code to be used later, you'll need to set a flag or save the exit code manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
warns=""
crits=""
for x in ...; do
    if warning_condition; then 
        warns=1                 # or keep a count with warns=$((warns + 1))
    elif critical_condition; then
        crits=1 
    fi
done
[ "$crits" ] && exit 2
[ "$warns" ] && exit 1
```

Or even

```
#!/bin/bash
exit_code=0
set_exit_code() { 
    # save the greatest given exit code
    [ "$1" -gt "$exit_code" ] && exit_code=$1
}
for x in ...; do
    if warning_condition; then 
        set_exit_code 1
    elif critical_condition; then
        set_exit_code 2
    fi
done
exit "$exit_code"
```

---

As for this...

```
$ ./purefs_check.sh  -w 50 -c 70 |grep WAR ;echo $?
```

it won't work as `$?` will hold the exit code of the `grep`. That could be used to find out if there were any output lines that contained `WAR`, but I don't think that's what you wanted.

If you want to sort the output warnings first, you'll need to collect the warnings and critical warnings to arrays, and print them at the end. Or just go through the data twice and look for warnings first, and criticals only after that.

Comment: Much appreciated . I can have the for loop as a function and call it for Warning and Critical ...

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
WarnSpace=$2
CritSpace=$2
```

and you invoke the script like

```
./purefs_check.sh  -w 50 -c 70
```

So the CritSpace value is 50.

You're not processing the options at all. Do this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

ST_OK=0
ST_WR=1
ST_CR=2
ST_UK=3

while getopts :w:c: opt; do
    case $opt in
        w) WarnSpace=$OPTARG ;;
        c) CritSpace=$OPTARG ;;
        *) echo "Warning: unknown option -$opt: ignoring it" >&2 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if [[ -z "$WarnSpace" ]]; then
    echo "Error: specify a warning threshold with -w" >&2
    exit $ST_UK
elif [[ -z "$CritSpace" ]]; then
    echo "Error: specify a critical threshold with -c" >&2
    exit $ST_UK
fi

warn=0
crit=0
while read -r volume SpaceUsed; do
    SpaceUsed=${SpaceUsed//[^[:digit:]]/}   # delete all non-digits

    if (( SpaceUsed >= CritSpace )); then
        echo "CRITICAL; $volume: total $SpaceUsed"
        ((crit++))
    elif (( SpaceUsed >= WarnSpace )); then
        echo "WARNING; $volume: total $SpaceUsed"
        ((warn++))
    fi
done < vol_list

((crit > 0)) && exit $ST_CR
((warn > 0)) && exit $ST_WR
exit $ST_OK
```

Comment: Thanks . Glenn . Space used should the position 4 of the file . Calculating the percentage .   SpaceUsed=${SpaceUsed//[^[:digit:]]/}  this is causing issues and giving all volumes as Critical . CRITICAL; dev_backup: total 1051200020170307095454172210016
CRITICAL; dev_client: total 2000020161025144206172230016

Comment: When I run this code with the vol_list file you provide, I get `CRITICAL; dr_prdoracle_bkup: total 83` and `WARNING; prd_backup: total 51` and the exit status is 2

Comment: "Space used should the position 4 of the file" -- what does that mean? what file?